# C# generic error, complains it can't convert between identical tuple types

Tags: c#, generics

trying to do my own zip, got this code (generic type param T is defined on the enclosing class of this method).

```
public List<(T, T2)> Zip<T, T2>(SQLList<T2> that)
            where T2 : LDBSQLemitter {
    var res = this.Zip(that).ToList();
    return res;
}
```

error is

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(T First, T2 Second)>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(T, T2)>'

What's this First/Second stuff in 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(T First, T2 Second)>', why is it missing in 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(T, T2)>' - - what is it about tuple types I don't understand here?

OK, use try instead to make an explicit conversion of each tuple, so

```
public List<(T, T2)> Zip<T, T2>(SQLList<T2> that)
                where T2 : LDBSQLemitter {
        var tmp = this.Zip(that).ToList();
    
        var res = new List<(T, T2)>();
        foreach (var x in tmp) {
            res.Add((x.First, x.Second));
        }
    
        return res;
    }
```

Now the error's completely baffling, apparently complaining it can't convert between 2 identical tuple types:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from '(T, T2)' to '(T, T2)'

Wassup?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: It's hard to say with just the code you've posted, but I suspect `T` and `T2` do not mean the same things in the error messages.  The error is telling you the name of the generic parameter, not what's bound to it.

Comment: Other compile errors could exist, concerning the code of `SQLList` a/o `LDBSQLemitter`

Comment: `var tmp = this.Zip(that).ToList();` in the body of `Zip` by the way will endlessly recurse and overflow, or am I missing sth?

Comment: @lidqy: quite likely, will find out shortly...

Comment: @PeterRuderman: You were right! Different T's. Trying to get a full working example (thanks, @mjwills) got it it to work, problem was unnecessary type param in zip decl, should have been just 'Zip<T2>', and using the class type param T directly, not shadowing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `this`, which the compiler can't relate to `T`.

It would help to know the signature of the class too. Does it also contain a generic parameter `T`? By also having a `T` generic parameter in the method you've defined `T` twice, and they are not the same.

You can fix it by explicitly casting this

`var res = ((IEnumerable<T>)this).Zip(that).ToList();`

or add Cast

`var res = this.Cast<T>().Zip(that).ToList();`

Or remove the extra T in the method

`public List<(T, T2)> Zip<T2>(SQLList<T2> that)`

Comment: Yeah, worked out I'd given an unnecessary extra type param to zip, see comments above. Answer accepted.